# Can you remember my tag filter preference between views?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, new-nav

(I'm assuming these changes will roll out, so I'm asking here rather than on meta.so)

One of the great things about the new UI is that I can get a full page of questions in my favorite tags. No more PHP questions in my face! Yay!

[image: PHP sucks a big ol hogleg amirite?]

But whenever I click on the Questions button,

[image]

I get the sad :( because it goes back to **all tags**

[image]

Eeew, look at all those gross tags. I threw up a little in my mouth.  Clicking on the StackOverflow logo is slightly better,

[image]

because that flips the tag filter over to *recommended*

[image]

That's the default, but why switch it when I click on the logo? Where's the logic in that?  And why does the "Questions" button mean "assault me with smelly PHP developers and their stinky questions"? I didn't ask for that. Honestly.

**Could you please remember my preference?**

Comment: @shadow you're no fun :(

Comment: I won't fall for that ;)